# Calculate the total of one measure (with a upper limit) in another measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I need to calculate the total value of a column per employee per month. Then I need to impose a limit of 177 per employee per month. This will go into a matrix with employee as rows and months as columns. Lastly, i want to add up all the amounts per month to show the total in a line chart.

I made a measure to calculate the 1% with a max of amount of 177= if(0.01*sum[amount]>177, 177,0.01*sum[amount]). Then I used this measure in my matrix as explained above. This worked fine, but when i want to make the line chart the limit of 177 is still imposed because I use the same measure.

Comment: `if(0.01*sum[amount]>177, 177,0.01*sum[amount])` is not a valid DAX expression and w/o  sample data and expected outcome this won't lead anywhere.

Comment: Hi Peter:
measure = if(0.01*SUM(Sheet1[Amount])>177,177,0.01*SUM(Sheet1[Amount])). This formula works for my matrix. The data is structured like Ozan demonstrated below.

My expected outcome= when I have a matrix with employees as rows and months as columns, I want this measure to calculate per employee per month. If the total for an employee for a particular month is >177, I want the 177 limit to be imposed for that month for that employee.

For the line chart= I want to add up the matrix amounts per month (not per employee), to summarise the results. This part is where I am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with some dummy data! Please do it like this:

```
Employee    Month   Amount
Jack    January     1500
Joe     February    20000
Joe     March       1600
Jack    April       1800
Brad    June        10000
Jack    July        9500
Joe     February    9500
Brad    April       6500
Jack    December    12000
Joe     June        8000
Brad    April       9500
Jack    January     1000
Jack    April       1100
Jack    April       8000
Joe     February    12000
Joe     February    12500
Joe     February    13000
Brad    June        15000
Brad    June        16000
```

Here is the measure (DAX Code)you need to use:

```
your_measure = 
if(0.01 * sum(your_table[Amount]) > 177, 177,0.01* sum(your_table[Amount]))
```

Then lets put it on a matrix and line chart:

[image: Line Chart + Matrix Visual]

If you want your 177 restriction not to be applied in line chart, Why not create another simple total measure:

```
= 0.01 * SUM(your table[amount])
```

Update requested from Peter

Now You need to check the whole picture! Employee is not a part of filter context. Model is filtered only by month! I added both measure as legends to the line chart!

[image: Whole_Picture]

Comment: Hi Ozan, thanks yes that is how the data is structured.
And thank you, the formula for the matrix is 100%.

The thing that will be an obstacle is that I cannot create a new total measure for the line chart. Because the 177 limit per month per employee has to be imposed. If I simply create a new measure like you suggest or even measure= 0.01 * sum(your_table[Amount]); I fear it will not be accurate. Because it will not be totalling up the matrix. So if you sense check the total of the line chart pm to the total of the matrix pm, there will be differences.

Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: It will be accurate if you know what you want to filter! I updated my answer! Please check the bottom part, and see the results! I am sorry if I misunderstood your request; but there is no reason for the results to be deviated from intended results if you know how to manage your model and filter context!

Comment: Hey Ozan, thanks for that. Looking good now.
I also found this formula that worked. Complicated, but also gives accurate results:
IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(Sheet1[Employee Code]))=1,[tax for the month],SUMX(VALUES(Sheet1[Employee Code]),[tax for the month]))

Comment: Yes, Your solution is also very good! You achieved it by using iterators! Quite good! Please accept my post as the answer if It has been useful. Other people having similar problems can find it easily then!